# AWS Glue - getSink() is throwing "No such file or directory" right after glue_context.purge_s3_path

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to purge a partition of a glue catalog table and then recreate the partition using getSink option (similar to truncate/load partition in database)
For purging the partition , I am using glueContext.purge_s3_path option with retention period = 0 . The partition is getting purged successfully .

```
            self._s3_path=s3://server1/main/transform/Account/local_segment/source_system=SAP/
            self._glue_context.purge_s3_path(
            self._s3_path,
              {"retentionPeriod": 0, "excludeStorageClasses": ()}
                )
```

Here Catalog database = Account , Table = local_segment , Partition_key = source_system

However when I am trying to recreate the partition right after the purge step , I am getting "An error occurred while calling o180.pyWriteDynamicFrame. No such file or directory" from getSink writeFrame .
If I remove the purge part then getSink is working fine and is able to create the partition and write the files .

I even tried "MSCK REPAIR TABLE" in between purge and getSink but no luck .

Shouldn't getSink create a partition if it does not exist i.e. purged from previous step ?

```
       target = self._glue_context.getSink(
            connection_type="s3",
            path=self._s3_path_prefix,
            enableUpdateCatalog=True,
            updateBehavior="UPDATE_IN_DATABASE",
            partitionKeys=["source_system"]
        )
        target.setFormat("glueparquet")
        target.setCatalogInfo(
            catalogDatabase=f"{self._target_database}",
            catalogTableName=f"{self._target_table_name}"
        )
        target.writeFrame(self._dyn_frame)
        
        Where - 
        self._s3_path_prefix = s3://server1/main/transform/Account/local_segment/
        self._target_database = Account
        self._target_table_name = local_segment
```

Error Message :

An error occurred while calling o180.pyWriteDynamicFrame. No such file or directory 's3://server1/main/transform/Account/local_segment/source_system=SAP/run-1620405230597-part-block-0-0-r-00000-snappy.parquet'

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have permission for this object on s3. I got the same error and once I configured the object to be public (just for test), it worked. So maybe it’s a new object and your process might not have access.